# Combining non-unique values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Wasn't able to find a specific answer on here, and I'm sorry if I'm vague at all, because I'm trying hard to understand what I'm asking.

I have a table called Data, which lets just say has the column set up of:

```
Id | X
```

A sample of this data would be:

```
Jon1 | a
Jon1 | a
Jon1 | d
Jon2 | b
Jon2 | c
Jon2 | d
Jon2 | c
```

I'm trying to get a count of x for ID. Say X has a 4 different possible values, we'll say a,b,c,d,e. What I want to do is get a total count of a,b,c,d for a unique ID. The desired outcome I want is:

```
Jon1 | 3
Jon2 | 4
```

I know this is probably possible through a COUNT subquery, but I'm not sure where to go on linking the counts to a certain ID. Does this make sense? It's kind of hard for me to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Tried this?

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY ID
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52e8f/2).

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking for a `DISTINCT COUNT` then this should be all you need

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(X)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id , COUNT(x) as Total FROM mytable GROUP BY id
```